# How to create a variadic ZipSequence type with Swift's parameter packs?

Tags: swift, parameter-pack

According to [SE-0398](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0398-variadic-types.md), we can now create types with a variable number of generic type parameters. The document uses `ZipSequence` as an example:

> In the generic parameter list of a generic type, the `each` keyword
> declares a generic parameter pack, just like it does in the generic
> parameter list of a generic function. The types of stored properties
> can contain pack expansion types, as in `let seq` and `var iter` below.
>
> This lets us define the return type of the variadic `zip` function as
> follows:
>
> ```
> struct ZipSequence<each S: Sequence>: Sequence {
>   typealias Element = (repeat (each S).Element)
>
>   let seq: (repeat each S)
>
>   func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
>     return Iterator(iter: (repeat (each seq).makeIterator()))
>   }
>
>   struct Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
>     typealias Element = (repeat (each S).Element)
>
>     var iter: (repeat (each S).Iterator)
>
>     mutating func next() -> Element? {
>       return ...
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

It unfortunately does not show how to implement the `next` method.

I tried implementing it as:

```
(repeat (each iter).next()!)
```

This produces the error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'τ_1_0.Iterator'

I know that I did not handle the case of `next` returning nil. Let's just assume that the sequences are all infinite - I just want to get to something that at least *compiles* first. Handling `next` returning nil is the least of my concerns, if I can't even write something that compiles.

How can I implement this `next` method?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `each iter` is an immutable value, so you can only pass it to functions expecting a non-inout `IteratorProtocol` parameter. That function can do `var copy = iter` to make it mutable, and return the modified `copy`, together with the next element:

```
// inside "next"
func nextHelper<I: IteratorProtocol>( _ iter: I) -> (I, I.Element) {
    var copy = iter
    let next = copy.next()!
    return (copy, next)
}
```

Then, if we do `(repeat nextHelper(each iter))`, we get a nested tuple structured like this:

```
((iter1, element1), (iter2, element2), ... (iterN, elementN))
```

All we need to do now is to create a tuple of all the `.0` of each nested tuple, and assign it to the `iter` property to update it. Then create a tuple of all the `.1` of each nested tuple, and return that as the next element.

```
// inside "next"
let nestedTuple = (repeat nextHelper(each iter))
iter = (repeat (each nestedTuple).0)
return (repeat (each nestedTuple).1)
```

To handle the case of `next` returning `nil`, I thought of a trick - to give `nextHelper` some side effect:

```
// inside "next"
var anyReachedEnd = false
func nextHelper<I: IteratorProtocol>( _ iter: I) -> (I, I.Element?) {
    var copy = iter
    if let next = copy.next() {
        return (copy, next)
    } else {
        anyReachedEnd = true
        return (copy, nil)
    }
}
```

When we do `(repeat nextHelper(each iter))`, `nextHelper` runs for every iterator. If any of the iterators returned `nil`, `anyReachedEnd` would be set to true.

```
// inside "next"
let nestedTuple = (repeat nextHelper(each iter))
if anyReachedEnd { return nil }
iter = (repeat (each nestedTuple).0)
return (repeat (each nestedTuple).1!)
```

I do think this is a bit "nasty". Perhaps there will be better ways to do this in future versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `each iter` is immutable, regardless of its storage seems to be a compiler limitation, which hopefully will be addressed soon.

The immutability can be circumvented, however, as you already did, just wanted to provide another solution that avoids the extra `Bool` property, by using exceptions:

```swift
func nextFor<I: IteratorProtocol>(for iterator: I) throws -> (I, I.Element) {
    var iterator = iterator
    guard let value = iterator.next() else { throw IteratorError.noMoreElements }
    return (iterator, value)
}
```

With the above in place, the `next` method can look like this:

```swift
mutating func next() -> Element? {
    do {
        let iterVal = try (repeat nextFor(each iter))
        iter = (repeat (each iterVal).0)
        return (repeat (each iterVal).1)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Combining everything together:

```swift
struct ZipSequence<each S: Sequence>: Sequence {
    typealias Element = (repeat (each S).Element)
    
    let seq: (repeat each S)
    
    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(iter: (repeat (each seq).makeIterator()))
    }
    
    struct Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
        typealias Element = (repeat (each S).Element)
        
        var iter: (repeat (each S).Iterator)
        
        mutating func next() -> Element? {
            do {
                let iterVal = try (repeat nextFor(each iter))
                iter = (repeat (each iterVal).0)
                return (repeat (each iterVal).1)
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

private func nextFor<I: IteratorProtocol>(_ iterator: I) throws -> (I, I.Element) {
    var iterator = iterator
    guard let value = iterator.next() else { throw IteratorError.noMoreElements }
    return (iterator, value)
}

private enum IteratorError: Error {
    case noMoreElements
}

func zip<each S: Sequence>(_ seq: repeat each S) -> ZipSequence<repeat each S> {
    ZipSequence(seq: (repeat each seq))
}
```

Usage example:

```swift
let zipped = Array(zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c", "d"], [true, false]))
print(zipped)
```

Output:

```
[(1, "a", true), (2, "b", false)]
```